# Setting a background image behind a bootstrap 5 navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to achieve something similar to this
[image: Goal]

This is what I have atm (bg-dark enabled just so text is visible)
[image: Current state]
As you can see theres quite a difference lol, I just need the image to go behind the taskbar, and then I need to know how to make the taskbar transparent

```html
<body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand mt-3">
            <div class="container-fluid bg-dark">
                <div class="w-100">
                    <img src="img/logo.png" class="ms-4" width="60" alt="Logo">
                    <button class="navbar-brand ms-5 fw-bold">TEST</button>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-nav justify-content-center">
                    <a class="nav-link text-light">One</a>
                    <a class="nav-link text-light">Two</a>
                    <a class="nav-link text-light">Three</a>
                    <a class="nav-link text-light">Four</a>
                </div>
                <div class="w-100"></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <img class="bg-img" src="backgrounds/index_background_top.png">
</body>
```

(Bootstrap 5)

Answer (score 1):

You need a wrapper `div` which contains `nav` and `contents`.
The div wrapper has a background-image CSS property.

Then you could add `background-color: transparent` to `nav` with adding a new class. For this,

- If you want to keep Bootstrap 5, You may need `!important` to override bootstrap css property.

### Your current code

`nav` and `img` are block elements. This is why the image is below the `nav` area.

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
<style>
.container{
background-image: url("backgrounds/index_background_top.png")
}
.navbar{
background:transparent !important;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand mt-3">
            <div class="container-fluid bg-dark">
                <div class="w-100">
                    <img src="img/logo.png" class="ms-4" width="60" alt="Logo">
                    <button class="navbar-brand ms-5 fw-bold">TEST</button>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-nav justify-content-center">
                    <a class="nav-link text-light">One</a>
                    <a class="nav-link text-light">Two</a>
                    <a class="nav-link text-light">Three</a>
                    <a class="nav-link text-light">Four</a>
                </div>
                <div class="w-100"></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thankyou! however as the image isnt the perfect dimensions, it just repeats as it is slightly too small, how can i make the background image stretch to the correct proportions -width wise; also, how can I make it so the whole image is generated, not just where there is text/content.

Comment: <style>
.container{
background-image: url("backgrounds/index_background_top.png")
background-size:100% 100%;
}
.navbar{
background:transparent !important;
}
</style>

Comment: Hello, That causes this https://imgur.com/a/Ry9wwwT

Comment: If you want it to be bigger. then you have to extend size of .container div. Image is fit to the size of container div. If you are planning to set image on background of more than one div then you have to split image and use those parts on each div background.